# js-data multiple models in a single route

Tags: javascript, jsdata

I'm using 3.0.0-rc.4 of js-data and I'm in need of loading multiple models from a single call to the backend API. I'm still building the backend as well and would prefer to be able to retrieve all the data from the different tables at one time instead of making multiple calls to different end points.

Answer (score 2):

You can. Say the route your web app is trying to load is /posts/123, and you need to load Post #123 and its Comments, which reside in two different tables. In your client-side app you can do something like

```
store.find('post', 123)
```

or even

```
store.find('post', 123, { params: { with: 'comment' } })
```

which will make a GET request to something like `/post/123` and `/post/123?with=comment` respectively.

Your backend can respond with the Post record with its Comments embedded, and as long as you've told JSData about the relationship between posts and comments they each will be cached into the right part of the in-memory store. For example:

```
store.defineMapper('post', {
  relations: {
    hasMany: {
      comment: {
        localField: 'comments',
        foreignKey: 'post_id'
      }
    }
  }
});
store.defineMapper('comment', {
  relations: {
    belongsTo: {
      post: {
        localField: 'post',
        foreignKey: 'post_id'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You do:

```
store.find('post', 123)
```

Your backend responds with:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  // ...
}
```

You do:

```
store.find('post', 123, { params: { with: 'comment' } })
```

Your backend responds with:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  // ...,
  comments: [
    {
      "id": 14323,
      "post_id": 123,
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

If you're using Node.js + JSData on the backend, than check out https://github.com/js-data/js-data-express which can parse the querystring correctlly and generate all of the Express routes for all of your Mappers. Using js-data-express your backend will be able to respond to the requests exactly as I indicated in my examples above.

Once you've loaded data into the in-memory store, your View component can pull the data it needs to display out of the in-memory store:

Get Post #123 out of the in-memory store:

```
store.get('post', 123)
```

Get the Comments for Post #123 out of the in-memory store:

```
store.getAll('comment', 123, { index: 'post_id' })
```

If you're using the `DataStore` component, then the Post's Comments should also be available on the Post record itself, e.g. `post.comments`.

Comment: great answer! I still have a follow up question though. So js-data is smart enough to resolve the plurals out of the received data since the storage object in the example is 'comment' but the received nested field is 'comments'?

Comment: JSData knows which field is the embedded relation by virtue of the "localField" setting in the relation definition.